# How to change the width of an item in a listview?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a winforms application with a listview that shows 6 items. The problem is that each item's width is too long so the user has to scroll to the right to see all of each item. 
How can I shorten the width of each rectangle for each item to match the width of the data inside the item/rectangle???

Thank you

Comment: Change the column widths?  (Assuming Details view)

Comment: Does it has any columns?

Comment: I am using List VIew

Comment: No I don't have any columns

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
ListviewName.View = View.Details
    ListviewName.Columns.Clear()
    ListviewName.Columns.Add("Columnn1", CInt(ListviewName.Width / divide))
```

add all your column.

divide value is depends on how many column in your Listview, but that's if you want all of your column size is equal.